# Viewholder Onclick - How to get reference to other views?

Tags: android

In my RecyclerView's ViewHolder class I have an OnClick method.

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

@BindView(R.id.vh_addphotosactivity_photonumber) TextView vhPhotoNumber;

public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
}

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       mPosition = getAdapterPosition();

       //How to reference other TextViews in the recycler?
    }
}
```

When any viewholder is clicked I want it to update all other TextViews. How would I get reference to other views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change values of the items from the list, rather than trying to access their TextViews itself. After that refresh you'r recycler using `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

You can add for example some onClickListener to constructor of your VH and implement it inside RecyclerView Adapter, so you can easily access list of items.

Comment: I have images as well in the recycler and I don't want to reload all of them if I only need to change the textview

Comment: Anyway you should update list items, you cannot change just textview because it's not available. RecyclerView has only few items (depends on screen size etc). If item is not visible, it's removed from memory and rebuild when it's visible again, base on data from list that you provide.


If you're using Glide or Picasso (or any other) then your images should be cached and reloading them will be really fast.